# How do I add custom bulk actions to multiple custom post types?

Tags: php, functions, theme-development, filters

I'm following [this tutorial](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/custom-bulk-actions.html) to add custom bulk actions to my dashboard but I have multiple custom post types. So far I was able to achieve what I want with

```
// functions.php

// The same line for each Custom Post Type
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-notre_offre', 'custom_bulk_actions' );
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-financements', 'custom_bulk_actions' );
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-le_groupe', 'custom_bulk_actions' );
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-actualites', 'custom_bulk_actions' );
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-ressources', 'custom_bulk_actions' );
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-legal', 'custom_bulk_actions' );
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-page', 'custom_bulk_actions' ); // default WordPress apges

function custom_bulk_actions( $bulk_array ) {
    $bulk_array['custom_bulk_make_draft'] = 'Draft';
    $bulk_array['custom_bulk_publish'] = 'Publish';
    return $bulk_array;
}

// [handler that also uses a bunch of add_filter()'s]
```

I feel like that's not the optimal way to do it.
Is there a way to merge all my `add_filter()` lines into one? Also, are there any negative effects on performance with the way I currently do this?

Comment: Your code is actually good, but if you don't want to having to add the `add_filter()` multiple times, then you can do something like `foreach ( array( 'notre_offre', 'financements', 'etc' ) as $id ) { add_filter( "bulk_actions-edit-$id", 'custom_bulk_actions' ); }` - i.e. replace all those `add_filter()` lines with that one `foreach` block.